# How to get the inverse of this function, when we have qudratic?

Tags: functions

$$f(x)=-x^2+6x-5$$ 
How do I find the inverse? I tried by making it 
$$y=-x^2+6x-5$$
Then swapping $y$ with $x$, and then solve it for y, but I got $y^2$.
The domain is $x$ greater or equal to $m$, and in this case $m=5$.

After that we need to find the domain of the inverse.

Comment: It says x is greater or equal to 5. @Arnaldo

Answer (score 0):

write your function in the form
$$0=x^2-6x+5+y$$ and then $$x_{1,2}=3\pm\sqrt{4-y}$$
can you finish?

Comment: So the domain of the inverse should be x is less than or equal to 0? But when I graph it, I see the function has x values for 4 or less.

Comment: yes it must be $$4-y\geq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
y
&=-x^2+6x-5\\
&=-(x^2-6x+9-9)-5\\
&=-(x^2-6x+9-9)-5\\
&=-((x-3)^2-9)-5\\
&=-(x-3)^2+4
\end{align}
$$
by completing the square so that
$$
4-y=(x-3)^2\iff \sqrt{4-y}=\lvert x-3\rvert
$$
But $x\geq 5$ so what can you conclude? Solve for $x$.

Comment: So why should be 0 or less? But when I graph $3+sqrt4-x$ then the function has x values for 4 or less.

Comment: @ JohnFire The original quadratic as stated in the problem has a maximum value of 4. It makes sense that the inverse function takes in values which are at most 4.

Comment: Yes, that would makes sense, but the answer in my book is x is less than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one is by completing the square

$f(x)=y=-((x-3)^2-4)$,

$4-y=(x-3)^2$,

$x=3\pm\sqrt{4-y}$.